# MYSQL: Many slave servers with smaller resources or less with larger resources

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-replication, database-performance, database-replication

I want to create High availability with Master Slave replication (for Select query).

I am wondering which one is better:

1. Having smaller resources slaves but more servers or
2. Having larger resources slaves but less servers

I only use One Master for modify query: (update / insert / delete)

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

The most likely thing to adjust in hardware is RAM.  If you tune `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to about 70% of RAM and that is bigger than the size of all the data, then there will be very little I/O.

If that is not practical (or too expensive), then if the "working set size" is small enough, you still get benefit for that cache.

Else you will need some I/O horsepower.

Don't worry about the speed or the number of CPU cores.  That is rarely the bottleneck.

Use this to discover which queries are in the most need for optimizing:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog

Add 2 cheap Replicas and see how well they perform, then come back with some more numbers to discuss.

Comment: My slave database is 16Gb, and this is the innodb config
innodb_buffer_pool_size=2G
innodb_buffer_pool_instance=7
is it good enough?

Comment: is that 70 percent of the database size no? that's what it has been answered to keep the i o low

Comment: ah yes, now I get it. I have set innodb_buffer_pool_size=12G, around 70%. but how many innodb_buffer_pool_instance to set?

Comment: The buffer_pool should be bigger than the dataset, but definitely not bigger than available RAM.  70% of _RAM_ is a good setting.